# Divide UIImage into two parts along a UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uibezierpath

How to divide this `UIImage` by the black line into two parts. The upper contour set of `UIBezierPath`.

[image]

I need to get two resulting `UIImage`s. So is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean you have a UIBezierPath storing the line?  Is it (1) a line, or (2) a closed curve around the upper right portion of the image?  If (2), you can draw the image to a new image context while clipping to the path.

Comment: Known to the entire upper figure. And it is possible more in detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following set of routines create versions of a UIImage with either only the content **inside** a path, or only content **outside** that path.

Both make use of the `compositeImage` method, which uses CGBlendMode.  CGBlendMode is very powerful for masking anything you can draw against anything else you can draw.  Calling compositeImage: with other blend modes can have interesting (if not always useful) effects.  See the [CGContext Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGBlendMode) for all the modes.

The clipping method I described in my comment to your OP does work and is probably faster, but only if you have UIBezierPaths defining all the regions you want to clip.

```
- (UIImage*) compositeImage:(UIImage*) sourceImage onPath:(UIBezierPath*) path usingBlendMode:(CGBlendMode) blend;
{
    // Create a new image of the same size as the source.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([sourceImage size]);

    // First draw an opaque path...
    [path fill];
    // ...then composite with the image.
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:blend alpha:1.0];

    // With drawing complete, store the composited image for later use.
    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Graphics contexts must be ended manually.
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return maskedImage;
}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage*) sourceImage toAreaInsidePath:(UIBezierPath*) maskPath;
{
    return [self compositeImage:sourceImage onPath:maskPath usingBlendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceIn];
}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage*) sourceImage toAreaOutsidePath:(UIBezierPath*) maskPath;
{
    return [self compositeImage:sourceImage onPath:maskPath usingBlendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceOut];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! All regions are known.

Comment: Why not draw uiiview? UIImage *image=[self maskImage:beginImage toAreaInsidePath:Figure];  [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

Comment: Please explain more.  Are you trying to show the image inside a UIView?  If so, putting those two lines inside the `drawRect` method should work.

Comment: http://zalil.ru/upload/33062738 Here is my project. lineviev.m draw image in drawRect, maskImage implemented in linemodel.m. section to do with the touches.

Comment: The UIBezierPath `figure` is being created with its top left corner at at `70,166`, where the image is displayed on the screen.  The mask methods require that the path have its top left at `0,0`.

Comment: How to reset a figure in CGPointZero?  figure.bounds.origin=CGPointZero - shows error

Comment: The bounds of a `UIBezierPath` are derived from its points.  You have to move the entire path, which you can do by transforming it.  `[figure applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-70, -166)]`.

Comment: You're welcome.  Know that the `-70,-166` is just where the image happens to be in your current prototype.  If the image moves, you'll need to move the `figure` by wherever its top left corner is.

Comment: How to draw lines on top of the added layers, with the help of touches?

Comment: That sounds like a different question.  Do you mind opening a new one, with more pictures of what you want to do?

Comment: http://zalil.ru/upload/33067470 The same project, only to add a view UIImageView. How do I draw the line on a UIImageView.

Comment: You will need to make sure the `UIView` that the lines are drawn on is on top of the `UIImageView`.  Also, at the moment your `drawRect` constructs a new `UIImageView` every cycle.  This uses up lots of memory and slow it down after dragging around for a bit.  This is not good use of StackOverflow; if you want more, please open a new question with a short and clear description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137289/orrectly-implement-the-blocks-in-the-drawing-view

Answer (score 2):

This can be done but it requires some trigonometry. Let's consider the case for the upper image. First, determine the bottommost end point of the `UIBezierPath` and use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to get the top part of the image above the line. This will look as follows:

[image: Top portion]

Now, assuming that your line is straight, move pixel by pixel along the line drawing vertical `stroke`s of `clearColor` (loop for top portion. Proceed on similar lines for bottom portion):

```
for(int currentPixel_x=0;currentPixel_x<your_ui_image_top.size.width)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(your_ui_image_top.size);
    [your_ui_image_top drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, your_ui_image_top.size.width, your_ui_image_top.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeClear); 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPixel_x, m*currentPixel_x + c);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPixel_x, your_ui_image_top.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    your_ui_image_top = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Your `UIBezierPath` will have to be converted to a straight line of the form `y = m*x + c`. The `x` in this equation will be `currentPixel_x` above. Iterate through the width of the image, increasing`currentPixel_x` by 1 each time. `next_y_point_on_your_line` will be calculated as:

```
next_y_point_on_your_line = m*currentPixel_x + c
```

Each vertical `stroke` will be 1 pixel wide and its height will depend on how you traverse through them. After some iterations, your image will look roughly (please excuse my poor photo-editing skills!) like:

[image]

There are multiple ways of how you draw the **clear** strokes and this is just one way of going about it. You can also have clear strokes that are parallel to the given path if it gives better results.

Another way is to set the alpha of the pixels below the line to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I tested clipping, and in a few different tests it was **25% slower** than masking to achieve the same result as the `[maskImage: toAreaInsidePath:]` method in my other answer.  For completeness I include it here, but please don't use it without a good reason.

```
- (UIImage*) clipImage:(UIImage*) sourceImage toPath:(UIBezierPath*) path;
{
    // Create a new image of the same size as the source.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([sourceImage size]);

    // Clipping means drawing only happens within the path.
    [path addClip];

    // Draw the image to the context.
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    // With drawing complete, store the composited image for later use.
    UIImage *clippedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Graphics contexts must be ended manually.
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return clippedImage;
}
```